# Replacing ' _' to ' ' embedded in the word using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, text

I have text datasets, say `df['text']'` that contains the word embedded with `'_'`. I would like to replace those `'_'` to `' '`. For example, if the word present in a text is `'overflow_largest'` then it should be `'overflow largest'`. So far I have written the following code:

```
import re
test_string = df['text']
p = re.compile(r"\b[a-z]+[a-z]*[a-z]\b")
print(re.findall(p,test_string))
```

Comment: `df['text'].str.replace("_", " ")`?

Comment: That code will not replace _ embedded in the word. It just replaces _ by white spaces.

Comment: What does *_ embedded in word* means? Show an example. It should transform `"overflow_largest"` into `"overflow largest"` or no?

Comment: deleted my answer since there is already a comment that says the same thing more concisely.

Comment: How do you want to handle a stray `_` at the end of the string? If you don't want to special case that (i.e. it should still be replaced with a space), you can avoid overlapping matches and do `re.sub(r'([a-z+])_', r'\1 ', 'foo_bar')`

Comment: @Alex028502 An answer is the correct place for something that, you know, answers the question.

Comment: @Ankita Both the first comment and the (deleted) answer do exactly what you want with `overflow_largest`. If you have something else in mind, please provide a sample input for which `str.replace` fails.

Comment: I just re_ran the model and now it worked with this simple code. Thanks